# How to know if a website uses server-side tracking?

Tags: facebook, server-side, tracking

I was wondering, is it possible for us users to know if a website uses server-side tracking?

For example, tracking to send events to Facebook, Google Tag Manager, etc.

Are there any indicators or tools we can use to find this out?

Comment: No, you can not determine what connections to other servers a site might be making, _from_ the server side.

Comment: Do you think there is another "indirect" way of checking if this is being used? I.e. checking specific cookie changes, etc.?

Comment: No, not really. Server-side tracking would not require any specific cookies to be set on the client side. A server you do not have access to, is a "black box" from your perspective. Impossible to find out what it might or might not do behind the scenes.